# How to Run Ionic React App after Building it

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, npm

My packages.json file has the following scripts:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
```

I perform a build with: npm run build
The result goes into the folder ./build where the dir hierarchy is as follows:

```
- assets
- static
- assets-manifest.json
- index.html
- manifest.json
- service-worker.js
- service-worker.js.map
```

If I'm in the build dir, how can I run the app? npm run start doesn't work because it looks for packages.json.

Ionic serve doesn't either since under the hood it still uses npm.

How can I run the app after it's built?